# FileUpload control upload video mp4

Tags: asp.net, video, upload, mp4

I use asp.net FileUpload to upload some file like mp4, mp3, jpg, png and psd. Every file work fine, but page just show me that the **The connection to localhost is interrupted** when I try to upload mp4 file. I don't know what is the error or problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a problem with request size limit, as MP4 files tend to be big. Very big. Try changing the config in your `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And check the file size before uploading.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what is 65536?

Comment: It's a size of your request - you can put almost any number there; 65536 is just a common one. There is more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx